# Is there a way to force links in an iframe to open in a new window? The iframe content is on a different domain

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I was wondering if there is a way to get links in an iframe to open in a new window.  The trick is the iframe content is on a different domain, and on that domain the links open in the same page.  I tried adding this to the html head

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

but it still opens in the iframe.  If this is impossible to do on a different domain let me know.

Comment: Sounds like a job for JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

This requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com) but should work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var baseTag= document.createElement('base');
    baseTag.target = '_blank';
    $("iframe html head").append(baseTag);
});
```

If it doesn't, then it's quite possibly because you can't access the contents of an iframe through jQuery. Not sure if you can or not.